# Rewriting .htaccess for https on subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, https, subdomain

I'm currently hosting subdomain `dev.example.com` from a `dev` subfolder and using these `.htaccess` rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?dev.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dev/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?dev.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ dev/index.html [L]
```

I bought SSL and want to change `.htaccess` rules to support both HTTP and HTTPS access, since `https://dev.example.com` is hitting the root of my hosting.

Can anyone provide a way to change it?

Comment: Why not fix it so that the http and https versions of the virtual hosts work the same way? In other words, why do you have the https version of dev.example.com hit the root of your hosting instead of the /dev/ subdirectory?

Comment: The SSL cert is a wildcard one and I have both example.com and dev.example.com on same hosting on same IP. The cPanel has created vhost for example.com only, so dev is defaulting to that one.

Comment: The `.htaccess` file already "supports both HTTP and HTTPS" - in that is does not differentiate between them. It's unclear why you think something needs to change here?